# Runaway process on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, process, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

We are running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and occasionally getting, what looks like a runaway process which starts hogging a lot of memory and CPU power.

In task manager I can see the process is a w3wp.exe (IIS worker process), and I can see the application pool attached to it. The problem is the same application pool is shared by many sites.

Is it possible to delve deeper into this process to try and glean more information as to what it's actually doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The odds are the w3wp is busy due to a site-specific errors in one or more of the web sites' code.

To narrow it down, create [Application Pools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735247(v=ws.10).aspx) for each individual web app; that way you will know which site is causing the [IIS Worker Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735084(v=ws.10).aspx) (w3wp) to get so busy.

Comment: Good suggestion but a little hard to implement due to our setup and the fact there are so many sites attached to the shard application pool. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: This is why these days the "best practice" is to have an app pool for each site, preferably each with their own user/credentials.